# Using CodeIgniter's word_censor() to replace values in a file

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, templates

I would like to know if this is the best practice with CI or if there is some better way. 
In my project I am sending a confirmation email during the registration process. I have a HTML and TXT template. They both consist of something like this:

`Hello {USERNAME}, please click on the activation link below to finish the registration. Link: {LINK}`

And in my method I open the templates using the file helper and then replace the `{}` strings with the actual values using the text helper's `word_censor()` method like this:

```
$tmpName = '{USERNAME}';
$tmpLink = '{LINK}';

$name = 'Jon' //retrieved from registration from
$link = 'mysite.com/activate/239dwd01039dasd' //runs the activate function providing the unique ID as an argument

$template = word_censor($template, $tmpName, $name);
$template = word_censor($template, $tmpLink, $link);

return $template
```

Then I just take the $template and put it inside the CI's mail helper like this:

`$this->email->message($template);`

What I would like to know is if this is the best way to replace contents of html/txt files with my own values or if there is any better and more efficient way to achieve the same result. I just don't like that I am using the `word_censor()` function to do something other than what it was intended for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to store the email template as a view file.

view

```
Hello <?php echo $username; ?>, please click on the activation link below to finish the registration. Link: <?php echo $link; ?>
```

Controller

```
$data['username'] = 'Jon';
$data['link'] = 'mysite.com/activate/239dwd01039dasd';

$email_template = $this->load->view('myfile', $data, true);
$this->email->message($email_template);
```

Setting the third parameter on `view()` to true will return the template rather then echo it out.